# Maven/Spring private repository setup

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Me and my team are pretty new to java side of things.
We have created a new rest service that uses spring framework.
We are trying to get the build automated.

We have our own repo that we want to go to find dependencies.
We put all third party dependencies in this repo and want the build to look into this repo while searching for dependencies.

Our pom.xml looks like this.

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       

</dependencies>
```

For these spring dependencies what are all the jars we need?
How do I find out which jars should we be having in our repo so that we can build our project?

Comment: If you want some maven repo. "local cache", you should take a look at tools like artifactory

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the repository to use in your pom file.  As an example we use a Nexus repository where we put other jars needed.  It also acts as a cache against the Central repositories so we don't need to explicitly include all of the jars that come from there.

You will need something like this in your pom.xml file:

```
<!-- location for other artifact uploads -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>YourRepositoryId</id>
        <url>http://yourrepo.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then your build automation will need a way to specify the user and password.  In a regular Maven setup you would use your user settings.xml file and populate it somewhat like this.  Different automated build systems may do it differently so you would need to see where yours gets it's Maven settings from.

```
 <!-- This exists so that environments without a user can still access the repository. -->
<settings>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>YourRepositoryId</id>
        <username>yourUserName</username>
        <password>yourPassword</password>
    </server>
</servers>
</settings>
```

In regard to determine the jar files to use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) is a good tool for analyzing a working build to see what is included.

Hopefully this helps but if not feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is part of the [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html).

If you also want to get the sources:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>sources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And look into the alternateLocation folder. And of course you can change that folder to your preferenced location.